# Problem of neovim with powerline-status

Tags: neovim, statusline

I have neovim 0.2.0 and powerline-status (2.6) on Fedora 26. But it fails as follows:

```
Se ha detectado un error al procesar function provider#python3#Call:
línea   18
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/powerline/vim.py", line 15, in <module>
    from powerline.bindings.vim import vim_get_func, vim_getvar, get_vim_encoding, python_to_vim
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/powerline/bindings/vim/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    vim_encoding = get_vim_encoding()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/powerline/bindings/vim/__init__.py", 
line 25, in get_vim_encoding
    return vim.options['encoding'].decode('ascii') or 'ascii'
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'powerline_setup' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'powerline_setup' is not defined
```

This is the CheckHealth report:

```
========================================================================
## Configuration
  - SUCCESS: no issues found

## Performance
  - SUCCESS: Build type: RelWithDebInfo

## Remote Plugins
  - SUCCESS: Up to date

## terminal
  - INFO: key_backspace (kbs) terminfo entry: key_backspace=\177
  - INFO: key_dc (kdch1) terminfo entry: key_dc=\E[3~

health#provider#check
========================================================================
## Clipboard (optional)
  - SUCCESS: Clipboard tool found: xsel

## Python 2 provider (optional)
  - INFO: `g:python_host_prog` is not set.  Searching for python2 in the environment.
  - INFO: Executable: /usr/bin/python2
  - INFO: Python2 version: 2.7.13
  - INFO: python2-neovim version: 0.1.13
  - SUCCESS: Latest python2-neovim is installed: 0.1.13
## Python 3 provider (optional)
  - INFO: `g:python3_host_prog` is not set.  Searching for python3 in the environment.
  - INFO: Executable: /usr/bin/python3
  - INFO: Python3 version: 3.6.2
  - INFO: python3-neovim version: 0.1.13
  - SUCCESS: Latest python3-neovim is installed: 0.1.13

## Ruby provider (optional)
  - INFO: Ruby: ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
  - INFO: Host: /home/sergio/bin/neovim-ruby-host
  - SUCCESS: Latest "neovim" gem is installed: 0.5.1
```

My .vimrc has:

```
python3 from powerline.vim import setup as powerline_setup
python3 powerline_setup()
python3 del powerline_setup
set laststatus=2
set t_Co=256
```

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this writing, it seems that the powerline plugin is still not compatible with NeoVim, check this github issue:

[Add support for NeoVim #1287](https://github.com/powerline/powerline/issues/1287)